# Why might Go +build tags introduce scoping issues?

Tags: go, build, scope, global-variables, undefined

I am writing a web server in Go lang, which needs to read a configuration file into memory before the server starts. I am having trouble accessing my `Settings` type, several variables, and a function which are defined in `settings.go`. These need to be accessible to other files within the same package, but I keep getting 'undefined' errors, suggesting I have some sort of scope error.

Below is a minimal code example which demonstrates my issue. Each file has `// +build go1.8` tags defined on the first line. With these tags present, compilation fails with the errors described below. Without these tags, compilation proceeds as expected.

**main.go**

```
// +build go1.8
package main

import (
    "myapp/srv"
)

func main() {
    srv.StartServer()
}
```

**server.go**

```
// +build go1.8
package srv

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    // read the server configuration file into memory
    err := ReadConfig(CFGFILE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("config error: %s", err)
    }
}

func StartServer() {
    fmt.Println("Starting server!")
    fmt.Println("Using config file at: " + CFGFILE)
    fmt.Println("Running on port: " + PORT)

    fmt.Print(Conf.String())

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + PORT, nil))
}
```

**settings.go**

```
// +build go1.8
package srv

import (
    /* Standard library packages */
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)


 /* All settings */
 type Settings struct {
    /* General settings */
    Title           string  // site title
    Subtitle        string  // site subtitle shown on landing page
 }

 // allow printing of runtime config
 func (s Settings) String() string {
    res, err := json.MarshalIndent(s, "", "  ")
    var ret string
    if err != nil {
        ret = "Error in config."
    } else {
        ret = string(res)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", ret)
}

// export global settings
var Conf Settings
var PORT string = "3000"
var CFGFILE string = "config.json"

func ReadConfig(file string) error {
    if file == "" {
        fmt.Println("Path to config file cannot be nil!")
    }

    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(buf, &Conf)

    return err
}
```

Compilation attempted with Go v1.8.3 on Fedora 26 Workstation by running `go build` from the project directory located at `$GOPATH/src/myapp`.

Errors:

```
./server.go:12: undefined: ReadConfig
./server.go:12: undefined: CFGFILE
./server.go:20: undefined: CFGFILE
./server.go:21: undefined: PORT
./server.go:23: undefined: Conf in Conf.String
./server.go:25: undefined: PORT
```

All of the above *are* defined in settings.go however, which to my knowledge should be included in the package when I execute `go build`. Any help would be appreciated.

*Project structure*:

```
myapp/
+- srv/
|  +- server.go
|  +- settings.go
+- main.go
```

UPDATE: Clarified questions to reflect new knowledge. I am fairly convinced that the build tags caused the issue outlined above.

Comment: The example code looks correct.  Try running `go vet` on your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. In `$GOPATH/src/myapp`, I run `go build` and it compiles fine. Where are you running `go build`? Is `$GOPATH` set correctly (though I don't need to set it to have things build correctly; testing w/ 1.9)?

Comment: @SnoProblem `go vet` doesn't output anything, and I gotta say that I'm really perplexed.

Comment: @RobNapier Honestly from all the docs I've read, I don't *think* I should be having any problems... I'm running `go build` from `$GOPATH/src/myapp`, and `go env GOPATH` returns what I expect it to.

Comment: I'd carefully check that `settings.go` is named correctly (in particular that it has a `.go` extension). The only way I can reproduce this so far is to move `settings.go` elsewhere or change its extension. I'd probably move all your `settings.go` code into `server.go` to see if that fixes things, and then try moving just one thing to another file (maybe a new file)

Comment: By way of copy-pasting with X-selections, I had accidentally omitted the `// +build go1.8` tags that I had at the top of each file. Removing these build tags allowed compilation to proceed as normal, like you suggested... I've updated the question. Now I'm wondering, why would these build tags introduce package scoping issues?

Comment: @KeeferRourke: built tags won't change scoping, they simply cause files to be included or _ommitted_ during compilation. Are you using the correct version of Go? Note that the build constraints as shown are not correct, as they need to be followed by a blank line too.

Comment: @JimB, if you want to write up a proper answer, I'll mark it as the accepted solution. I am now fairly certain that the issue arose due to incorrect build tag usage.

Comment: @KeeferRourke: I'm not sure what to put, because I don't see how it wouldn't have worked. You are using the correct version of Go, and the build tags aren't formatted correctly, so they wouldn't take effect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Exported code from other packages has to be prefixed with the package name.

```
package foo

func Bar() { ... }
```

and

```
package main

import foo

func main() {
    foo.Bar() 
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Note that the two source files intentionally belong to the same package.

Comment: I have updated the code example to be more clear. My question concerns a custom package that I am writing which is split across multiple files. These files *should* share the same package scope, by my understanding, but do not see to.

Comment: @Mue, While this is factually correct, it has nothing to do with the issue in question.

Comment: @JimB I know, has been written immediately after the question has been entered. Here the packages in the code missed. See history of the question.